# python nan != nan

Tags: python, math, nan

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> id(x) == id(x)
True
>>> x == x
False
```

I'm interested in how `nan != nan` in python.  And just to clarify, I know `nan` is supposed to behave like that by definition, I'm asking about *how* not about why.  Where is that implemented?  Is there any other object which behaves like that?

Comment: I would expect that `==` does floating point comparison for floats, so that would give you `NaN != NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "where" part of your questions, look starting at line 391 in Objects/floatobject.c in the Python 2.7.3 source tree. A brief discussion is given about the behavior of NaN == NaN with the implementation following.

With respect to other cases that exhibit similar behavior, it is certainly possible. I have not done an exhaustive search of the libraries however, so I can't give a definitive answer.

Comment: Interesting!  It's _very_ complex .. The [implementation](http://www6.uniovi.es/python/dev/src/c/html/floatobject_8c.html#a34) is several hundred lines long spaghetti, full of macros, gotos etc

Answer (score 5):

Not A Number (NaN) is unequal with anything. To detect it, use `math.isnan`. And an object like this is quite easy to define:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True
```

The reason why this is is quite simple. CPython follows the IEEE 754 standard for floating point math. NaN is a floating point value for which IEEE 754 dictates that it is not equal to any other floating point value.

Comment: exactly, it doesn't answer the quesiton.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: updated the question with why this behaviour is chosen.

Comment: Does CPython really follow the IEEE 754 standard?  I mean, doesn't it just inherit its behaviour from the system it's running on?  IIRC that caused problems sometimes on other (nonstandard) architectures, and the response was basically "CPython doesn't promise that floats will behave how you want them to".  But I'm vaguely remembering something I read once, so reader beware.

Comment: @DSM: for all practical purposes, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The machine code that implements floating point operations handles the result of operations with NaN. For the x86 processor series this is usually achieved using x87 coprocessor instructions, although for earlier x86 processors where an x87 coprocessor was not always present a compiler usually provided emulation code.

Comment: reading John's answer below, now i'm not so convinced it's the machine code for floats - they seem to handle special cases etc. and there is this comment in the source:  `Comparison is pretty much a nightmare.  When comparing float to float,
we do it as straightforwardly (and long-windedly) as conceivable, so
that, e.g., Python x == y delivers the same result as the platform
C x == y when x and/or y is a NaN.`

Comment: @wim My "machine code" was hand-wavy for "the platform C x == y".