# numpy.isnan(value) not the same as value == numpy.nan?

Tags: python, numpy, types, boolean, nan

Why am I getting the following:

```
>>> v
nan
>>> type(v)
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>> v == np.nan
False
>>> np.isnan(v)
True
```

I would have thought the two should be equivalent?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/325565  (not directly python-related, but written by a member of the IEEE-754 committee that defined why this is the way it is)

Comment: I guess it makes sense that two undefined values cannot be compared as identical because they are by definition undefined. Just a little confusing when you get a nan != nan error the first time!

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13003202/674039

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`nan != nan`. That's just how equality comparisons on `nan` are defined. It was decided that this result is more convenient for numerical algorithms than the alternative. This is specifically why `isnan` exists.

Comment: Thanks! That thoroughly confused me for a while when debugging :)

Comment: By the way, this is likely due to IEEE 754 which states: *Four mutually exclusive relations are possible: less than, equal, greater than, and unordered. The last case arises when at least one operand is NaN. Every NaN shall compare unordered with everything, including itself.*  Edit: Looks like I was beaten by ~2 hours by a comment with a link that goes into more detail -- see Joe Kington's comment to the question.