# What is the proper way to deal with `float('nan')` in Python sets?

Tags: python, set, nan

The number `float('nan')` causes some serious problem in Python sets. For instance, look at the following:

```
S = set()
S.add(float('nan'))
S                    # {nan}
S.add(float('nan'))
S.add(float('nan'))
S                    # {nan, nan, nan}
len(S)               # 3
```

Sets are supposed to have only one entry of each type, but each `float('nan')` has been added as a separate item. But things get even more complicated when you try to remove them.

```
float('nan') in S    # False
S.remove(float('nan'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: nan
```

OK, every test against `float('nan')` evaluates to `False`, even `float('nan') == float('nan')`, but the consequences for sets are counter-intuitive (at least to me). So, what to do in practice about the following three problems:

1. How to know the number of *different* objects in a Python set given that `float('nan')` may have been added?
2. How to know if a set contains `float('nan')`?
3. How to remove `float('nan')` from a set?

Is the answer to always check before and never, ever add `float('nan')` to a set?

Comment: Do you really need to store NaNs? How are they being used? You could use [`isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan), and insert an "indicator" value as a substitute if the value is NaN.

Comment: Avoid adding NaN to a `set` at all costs. To test for nan, use `import math; print(math.isnan(float('nan')))`

Comment: This doesn't directly address the question, but helps explain why @juanpa.arrivillaga is right: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13003202/535275

Comment: @Carcigenicate You usually do not know it. Think that you can parse large text files with missing data, or where the results can produce `float('nan')`. The problem with `float('nan')` is that you often do not know they are there at all.

Comment: @gui11aume If they're possible, you're probably going to have to do checks prior, then decide how to deal with them once you find them. Like I mentioned, you could substitute them with a custom indicator like `NaN_holder = object()`, then `if math.isnan(n): s.add(NaN_holder) else: s.add(n)`, then decide how to handle `NaN_holder` once you're actually using the data.

Answer (score -1):

Something like the code below can work.

Note that it does string comparison so it may be slower than the native set.

```
class NanFriendlyFloatSet(set):
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
            def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
                if attr.__name__ == 'add' and str(args[0]).lower() == 'nan':
                  return
                result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                return result
            return new_func
        else:
            return attr

S1 = NanFriendlyFloatSet()
S1.add(float('nan'))
S1.add(float('nan'))
S1.add(float(34.6))
S1.add(float('nan'))
print(len(S1))
for x in S1:
  print(x)
```

output

```
1
34.6
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! If anything, instead of ignoring `float('nan')`, I think it would probably be better to replace them by a holder, as suggested by @Carcigenicate. Alternatively, you can even throw an exception to force the user to act on the presence of `float('nan')` (after this they do what they want).