# Nan values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy

Am Trying to print if there is a nan value in a list of dictionaries but failed to do so.

```
data = [{'A' : 2, 'B' : 'ssss'}, {'A' : 3, 'B' : 'xxx'}, {'A' :nan, 'B' : 'ssss'}]
```

Code :

```
for x in data:
    if (x['A']== 2):
        print('two')
    elif (x['A']== np.nan)
        print('null')
    else:
        print('nothing')
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003202/python-nan-nan for why `x['A']== np.nan` is not going to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain the dictionary's values using `dict.values`, in this case we can just `map` with this method, and check if `any` values in the returned generator are unequal to themselves, meaning that they are `NaN`:

```
from itertools import chain
data = [{'A' : 2, 'B' : 'ssss'}, {'A' : 3, 'B' : 'xxx'}, 
        {'A' :float('nan'), 'B' : 'ssss'}]
```

---

```
any(i!=i for i in chain.from_iterable(map(dict.values, data)))
# True
```

---

Or following the logic in your code:

```
for x in data:
    if (x['A']== 2):
        print('two')
    elif (x['A']!= x['A']):
        print('null')
    else:
        print('nothing')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.isnan()` instead:

```
for x in data:
    if (x['A']== 2):
        print('two')
    elif (np.isnan(x['A']))
        print('null')
    else:
        print('nothing')
```

Sources:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/misc.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `if (x['A'] is np.nan)` instead of `==`